# App Engine Python: How to properly redirect to a template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect

This code renders out a template **'sites.htm'** in response to the POST request:

```
def post(self):
        acct = self.request.get('account')
        pw = self.request.get('password')

        que = db.Query(User)
        que = que.filter('account =', acct)
        que = que.filter('password =', pw)
        results = que.fetch(limit = 1)

        values = { }
        newval = dict(values)
        newval['path'] = self.request.path

        if len(results) > 0:
            arraySample = ['6','7','8','ninja']
            path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/sites.htm')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {'arraySample':arraySample,'message':'Ninja IDE'}))
```

But I want my application to respond to that login attempt by redirecting to **'sites.htm'** with the parameters of a dictionary.

I can't just do  `self.redirect('sites.htm')` because the elements from the dictionary won't be shown.

Is there a way I can pass the dictionary as a url parameter to **redirect()** method?

Thanks in advance and I hope I was clear enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the dictionary in the query string. HTTP 101

```
import urllib
self.redirect("sites.htm?%s" % urllib.urlencode(dict(a="this and that", b="back and forth)))
```

Comment: thanks Tom. But do you know how should I access the data of the dictionary from the template? I cannot print it by doing: {% if a %} {{ a }} {% endif %}

Comment: my guess would be with the same request.get(...) that is up there in your question.

Comment: by the way , you are now asking a completely different question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know what I was thinking. Your solution does what I wanted to achieve and works =)

Answer (score 1):

you can't pass parameters to the redirect function.

what you could do is or redirect with url parameters which is a little bit ugly to me.
the second option is to set a cookie with those values, redirect to the url you want and read those values in your get function to pass them to the template.

Comment: thanks aschmid00. I expressed myself wrong, I was talking about passing 'url parameters' to the redirect function. But how should I do to pass the 'arraySample' array to the template?